# Linux Shutdown Order

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, google-cloud-platform, shutdown

Gracefully shutting down a system ( using "shutdown" command ), terminates all the services registered under systemd in order and also send kill signal to all the running processes to give them a chance gracefully shut down.

Is there any specific order in which kill signal is sent to the processes which are not registered as service in systemd?

Is any any order between systemd services shut down and kill signal sent to other processes?

I've a java application process running on a VM and want that it's terminated only after a particular service registered under systemd has terminated. Is there any other way to achive this thing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [How does the system shutdown of a linux kernel work internally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122557/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/); and [How to stop systemd services in specific order](https://serverfault.com/q/785127/145545) and [How can I predict systemd's shutdown order?](https://serverfault.com/q/764495/145545) on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

I would not count on non-service process order, because it might not exist or depend on OS flavors / versions.
How about creating our service which controls the process start/stop order and adding it to the system?

Comment: yeah, it does makes sense. I'll try this if I'm not able to find any direct way to  define order between service and non-service processes. thank you.